# Insert 'Space' element between subscripts text and closing bracket

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest to insert *space* between subscript(msub) text and closing bracket ')', where 'p' is the first child or first child's descendant text. (xsl:template match will have the text like braces ')'.)

There some criteria to insert the spaces between text 'p' and close bracket ')'. (In below text, assume p2) as <sub><mi>p</mi><mn>2</mn></sub>).

*Template match must from 'mo' where it contains closing bracket ')'*. See comments (ignore those) to explain the required result. Please suggest.

- **p2)** - to **p2<space/>)** - space required between 'p2' and ')', as 'p' is first child text of 'msub' or subscripts text.
- **p2+a)** - to **p2+a<space/>)** - space required between 'p2+a' and ')', space required, as 'p' is first child text of 'msub' or subscripts text, and remaining text will come in subscript's second text. From bracket first preceded text belongs to SUBSCRIPT.

**XML:**

```
<article>

<math id="m1">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mi>p</mi>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>r</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mn>8</mn>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m3">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m4">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m5">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <mi>p</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mi>t</mi>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mo">
    <xsl:variable name="varPreceded2">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][2][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., ')') and matches($varPreceded2, '^(f|j|p|y|g)$') 
            and 
            preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][2][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)] 
            is 
            (preceding::msub[1]/*[1]/descendant-or-self::*[text()][1])">
            <mspace/><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result** (comments for explaining the required result)

```
<article>

<math id="m1">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mi>p</mi>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mspace/><!-- Here Space required,  because 'before closing bracket first preceded text belongs to MSUB element, and first child of MSUB is having 'p'-->
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>r</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mn>8</mn>
    <!-- Space is not required here, because 'p' is not first child's desendant text, that is second ones-->
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m3">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mspace/><!-- Here Space required,  because 'before closing bracket first preceded text belongs to MSUB element, and first child of MSUB is having  'p'-->
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m4">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mspace/><!-- Here Space required,  because 'before closing bracket first preceded text belongs to MSUB element, and first child of MSUB is having  'p', 'p' is not preceded[2] text, even thou bracket's preceded text is SUBSCRIPT's text where 'p' is first child's text-->
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m5">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <mi>p</mi>
    <mi>t</mi>
    <!-- Space not required because 'p' not a part of SUBSCRIPT -->
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help **generate-id()**, I got the required result...

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mo">
  <xsl:variable name="varPreceded">
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding::msub[1]/*[1]/descendant-or-self::text()[1]
      [generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]
      [generate-id(current()/preceding::msub[1]/*[2]/descendant-or-self::text()[last()])
         =
       generate-id(current()/preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][1])]"/>
  </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., ')') and matches($varPreceded, '^(f|j|p|y|g)$')">
            <mspace/><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML:**

```
<article>

<math id="m1">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mi>p</mi>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>r2</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mn>8</mn>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m3">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m4">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m5">
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mo>(</mo>
    <mi>p</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mi>t</mi>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

</article>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<article>

<math id="m1">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mi>p</mi>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <mspace/><mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>r2</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mn>8</mn>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m3">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mspace/><mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m4">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mspace/><mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m5">
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mo>(</mo>
    <mi>p</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mi>t</mi>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, from "mo" instead:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"               version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mo">
        <xsl:if test="contains(., ')') and preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='msub'] and contains(preceding-sibling::msub[1]/child::*[1], 'p')">

            <xsl:comment>Space here</xsl:comment>
            <space/>
        </xsl:if>
        <mo>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </mo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is:

```
 <article>

<math id="m1">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mi>p</mi>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </msub>
    <!--Space here--><space/><mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>r</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <mn>8</mn>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m3">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
    </msub>
    <!--Space here--><space/><mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m4">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <msub>
        <mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>s</mi></mrow>
    </msub>
    <!--Space here--><space/><mo>)</mo>
</math>

<math id="m5">
    <mo>(</mo>
    <mi>p</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mi>t</mi>
    <mo>)</mo>
</math>

</article>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, plus one, but space is inserting even 'sub' is not immediate before the close bracket. ex: <math id="m8"><msub><mrow><mi>p</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msub><mo>(</mo><mi>p</mi><mn>2</mn><mi>t</mi><!--Space here--><space/><mo>)</mo></math>. Still I am waiting for suggestions...

Comment: So its a new requirement (that sample is not listed in your sample or did I miss something).  Add a test for preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='msub'] as shown above to test if the immediate preceding-sibling is named 'msub' ... I think that is your new requirement.

Comment: Sorry, but Question is stating SPACE between SUB and closing BRACKET, see the bullet list points.

Comment: What part of contains (.')') Would apply to anything but a closing bracket. The xsl above yields your exact result before closing bracket.

Comment: yes, but subscripts is not immediate preceded side also <space/> inserted, my requirement is inserting this element between subscripts text and the bracket, see the second bullet point there mentioned as 'subscript should be first preceded text to bracket'.

Comment: Ok. That is why the template was modified with preceding-sibling::*[1][ name ()='msub'] to guarantee the mp in question is immediately following an msub

Comment: But in MathML there may be other elements can wrap the 'msub', then 'preceding-sibling::*[1]' not able to get the preceded 'msub'.

Comment: OK, no reason to carry on then. You should think about this exchange for your next post. It is a complete waste of time on SO users to attempt to solve a problem where you have not presented the entire problem through your examples and description. Neither of the above requirements are in your question. Since you were the one that knew all the requirements, only you could answer it.

Comment: Kevin, I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience, I think I may miss the few more examples in my post, maximum cases I kept, again I am extremely sorry, this answer even I got after two days only. My intention was how to use the 'IS' facility check the preceded text is both 'Sub content as well as first preceded to bracket'.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Matching on msub would be much easier I think:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="msub">
    <msub>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </msub>


        <xsl:if test="contains(following-sibling::mo,')') and contains(child::*[1],'p')">
            <space/>
        </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I need xpath from template match 'mo'.

Comment: Why? I cannot see any reason to make the task harder but perhaps you have some reason you have not posed in the question.

Comment: Not only space insertion, some attribute needs to insert for the element 'MO', that's why TEMPLATE MATCH from MO only. (Here i haven't given attribute format, just i need such 'MO' identification).